# Google spreadsheet adding values in the same field?

Tags: excel, google-sheets

I have a google spreadsheet which tracks my monthly expenses etc. I update this on a daily basis.

e.g:

```
Type     Expense

Fuel     £200
Rent     £800
Food     £500
Internet £40
Utility  £350
```

My question is simple. How do I make the expense field auto add new expenses? Say I purchased food for £100 and now instead of deleting the £500 value and adding £600 I want to either click the field and type £100 and it gets updated to £600 OR when I click it opens a popup with a input field and when I put £100 it adds the number with the existing value £500 and gives an updated number £600?

How to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: A simple idea would be to have an additional column, say, Expense Details, where you can itemize the actual expense like Dinner out, Lunch out, Grocery, etc for Food type of expense. Then you can apply `Sum`.

Comment: Thanks. But I have more than one field here for every month so this option is not practical :(

Comment: Haven't looked into Google Spreadsheet in detail ... can you use `Pivot` table there?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the same cell you are using to display the total expense as an input for additional ones. However you can create a "Form" (under "Tools").

On the forms page, you can "Add item" for each expense. Set the "Question Type" to "Text" and in "Data Validation" check "Number".

Click on "View Live form" to get the URL. Use this in a hyperlink() to serve as a "button" in your spreadsheet.

`Type    Total Expense       Update Expense
Fuel        200             Update Fuel
Rent        800             Update Rent
Food        500             Update Food
Internet    40              Update Internet
Utility     350             Update Utility`

The form should be in your Google Drive, in the same folder as your spreadsheet should you decide to edit it afterwards. If you want, you can also save the URL of the form as an "Additional Expense" hyperlink.

All the data will be collected in a "Form Responses" sheet. From there, you can simply get the sums or sumifs.